# How to make global.json look two folders up

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I use beta6 and have the following structure:

```
-RootFolder
---Proj1
---Proj2
---SolutionFolder
------Proj3 (References Proj1)
------Proj4
------ASP.NET5 project
------Blablabla.sln
------global.json
```

All projects are in the same solution file, but there's the following issue:
If I simply add the reference to Proj3 in my ASP.NET5 project, its Proj1 dependency cannot be automatically resolved.

I believe that the main reason for this is that Proj1 is two levels above the solution folder. In addition, it is somewhat confirmed by the error message if I press View => Chrome:

```
Failed to resolve the following dependencies for target framework 'DNX,Version=v4.5.1':
  Proj1 1.0.0

Searched Locations:
 {pathToSolutionFolder}\{SolutionFolder}\{name}\project.json
 {pathToSolutionFolder}\{SolutionFolder}\wrap\{name}\project.json
 C:\Users\{me}\.dnx\packages\{name}\{version}\{name}.nuspec
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\{name}.dll
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\Facades\{name}.dll
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\{name}\{version}\{name}.dll
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64\{name}\{version}\{name}.dll
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\{name}\{version}\{name}.dll
```

"wrap" is listed in global.json, so it tries to search in the solution folder only.

I tried to add something like ".." there, but it just searches like that:

```
{SolutionFolder}\..\{name}\project.json
```

Is there a way to list a folder that is two levels above the solution folder in global.json? Specially my "RootFolder".

If there's no way, then how to correctly reference that Proj3 so that its dependencies are resolved?
(I hoped that everything would be done automatically when I referenced the project from my solution :C )